# How to change to arrow function without bind?

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller

Please help to change this part of code into an arrow function without bind:

```
this.element.push(setTimeout(this.setSomething.bind(this), 1000 - (new Date()).getMilliseconds()));
```

Comment: Just use `() => this.setSomething()`, or paste the function there directly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Arrow function expressions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions) have a "lexical this", meaning that their target will be the `this` value present at the point of their declaration.

```
this.element.push(setTimeout(() => this.setSomething(), 1000 - (new Date()).getMilliseconds()));
```